# How can I lower the dimension of a list

Tags: python, list

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
c=[]
c.append(a)
c.append(b)
print(c)
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

the code goes like this but how can I make `c` into `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`?

Comment: Use `c.extend()` or simply `c = a + b`

Answer (score 1):

You could also merge both lists into `c` using the addition operator. For example:

```
c = a + b
```